# How to change Time format in R?

Tags: r, datetime, format

I have added a new column RIDE_LENGTH using mutate function as follows.

df2 <- mutate(df2, RIDE_LENGTH = (ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT)
ENDED AT & STARTED AT is in HH:MM:SS format, but my new column is showing the result in seconds only
example : 12:05:00 - 12:03:00 = 120 secs.
I need the answer to be in the same format as 00:02:00.
If anyone can tell me how to do that would be a great help.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
library(lubridate)
RIDE_LENGTH <- seconds_to_period(RIDE_LENGTH)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am getting error as "Error in seconds_to_period(RIDE_LENGTH) : object 'RIDE_LENGTH' not found".
 I ran 
df2 %>%  
  select(RIDE_LENGTH).
I am able to see RIDE_LENGTH column.

Comment: try `df2 %>% select(seconds_to_period(RIDE_LENGTH))`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways in the `lubridate` package, depending on your desired output. Take your pick:

```r
library(dplyr)

df  <- data.frame(
  STARTED_AT = as.POSIXct("2022-06-06 12:03:00 UTC"),
  ENDED_AT = as.POSIXct("2022-06-06 12:05:00 UTC")
)

df  |>
  mutate(
    RIDE_LENGTH_base = ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT,
    RIDE_LENGTH_lubridate_difftime = lubridate::as.difftime(ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT), 
    RIDE_LENGTH_period = lubridate::as.period(ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT), 
    RIDE_LENGTH_duration = lubridate::as.duration(ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT)    
    )
#            STARTED_AT            ENDED_AT RIDE_LENGTH_base RIDE_LENGTH_lubridate_difftime RIDE_LENGTH_period RIDE_LENGTH_interval
# 1 2022-06-06 12:03:00 2022-06-06 12:05:00           2 mins                         2 mins              2M 0S    120s (~2 minutes)
```